# Using Mod Rewrite to change URL structure

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to use mod rewrite via htaccess for a PHP website.

URL structure is the following:

```
example.com/ex.php?ez=DF004AE
```

It must become:

```
example.com/ex/DF004AE.htm
```

What is the correct script to add to my .htaccess in order to do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: Does the new url exist?

Comment: no, it's just a pretty link for SEO

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ex/([^/]*)\.htm$ /ex.php?ez=$1 [L]
```

It will give you the following URL:

`example.com/ex/DF004AE.htm`

If you meant it to be .html (not .htm) Just add the l in the RewriteRule.

Comment: Again, I thought the question was asking the opposite, i.e.f from the query string URL to the pretty one.

Comment: Exactly how I read it @apokryfos ! The OP has asked for the URL `example.com/ex.php?ez=DF004AE` to become `example.com/ex/DF004AE.htm`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following rules :

```
RewriteEngine on
# Redirect from "/ex.php?ez=foobar" to "/ex/foobar.htm"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /ex\.php\?ez=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /ex/%1.htm? [L,R]
####################
# internally map "/ex/foobar.htm" to "/ex.php?ez=foobar"
RewriteRule ^ex/([^.]+)\.htm$ /ex.php?ez=$1 [NC,L]
```

This will convert `/ex.php?ez=foobar` into `/ex/foobar.htm` .

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ex/([^/]*)\.html$ /ex.php?ez=$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

If you don't want the address bar to reflect this change, remove R=301. The NE parameter is there to make sure that the request is not escaped.